# Sending JSON from WebApi to Android

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have problem understanding sending Json from WebApi to Android. I know how to make requests from Json, but don't know how to make Task that waits for request and return Json. I have json made from Mongo DB query with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

I have been searching and found this that I have for now, but this isn't what I need I think, I don't have url in `PostAsync`, I just want to wait for request and respond with Json, where I need to look for:

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> SendAsync()
{
    var content = new StringContent(
            jsonString,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_url, content);

    return response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to **send json to android in WebApi** or **receiving json from WebApi in android**?

Comment: I want to request JSON from Android, and mine Web Api return JSON on that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an `IHttpActionResult` implementation. For example:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendAsync()
{    
    // Object passed to Ok will be automatically serialized to JSON
    // if response content type is JSON (and, by default, this is the serialization
    // format in ASP.NET WebAPI)
    return Ok(new { text = "hello world" });
}
```

Comment: But.... What is _url in PostAsync. What url I need? Because I just want Api handle request from android

Comment: @Sasaman So I removed that part. Now you know how to return JSON from WebAPI. Now it's up to you to know what you're sending to your own WebAPI from your Android app.........

Comment: I will post new question, because I have problem retrieving JSON when targeting my controler, I get StatusCode -1. I C/P your code with Hello World just to test it, please follow my new Question, If  it works I will mark this answer. If I do something wrong on other side.